# `ssh` executable not found in any directories in the %PATH%

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile

ERROR:

```
c:\Users\dhawal.vora>vagrant ssh
`ssh` executable not found in any directories in the %PATH% variable. Is an
SSH client installed? Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all of which
contain an SSH client. Or use your favorite SSH client with the following
authentication information shown below:

Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 2222
Username: vagrant
Private key: c:/Users/dhawal.vora/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Kindly help????

Vagrant file is below-

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
# The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
# For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
# https://docs.vagrantup.com.

# Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
# boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
config.vm.box = "precise32"

# Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
# boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
# `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
config.vm.box_check_update = false

# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

# Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
# Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
# your network.
config.vm.network "public_network"

# Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
# the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
# the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
# argument is a set of non-required options.
config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

# Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
# backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
# Example for VirtualBox:
#
# config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
#   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
#   vb.gui = true
#
#   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
#   vb.memory = "1024"
# end
#
# View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
# information on available options.

# Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
# such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
# https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
# config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
#   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
# end

# Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
# Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
# documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
# config.vm.provision "shell", inline <<-SHELL
sudo apt-get install apache2
# SHELL
end
```

Comment: You need run the command in the same directory where you put `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: I did that but to vain...

Comment: can you paste file `Vagrantfile` in your question?

Answer (score 85):

Adding `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the PATH environment variable.

Add it manually or I believe you could run this in cmd:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

#### updated from @Ygor Thomaz's comments

or (64 bits)

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, go through :

[Get SSH working on Vagrant/Windows/Git](https://gist.github.com/haf/2843680)

Comment: or (64 bits) set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

Comment: Worked for me but restarting windows after setting the path! also have a look at: http://blog.osteel.me/posts/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vagrant-on-windows.html

Comment: Why does adding Git\usrs\bin to the path help? Is git what provides the "ssh client" for vagrant?

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively install `openssh` from [here](http://openssh.en.softonic.com/download) and then you can add the `ssh.exe` to your PATH by:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin
```

or

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 10 I also couldn't get the 'set PATH' option to work.  But when I amended the PATH variable through System Settings and started a new command prompt it worked fine.

Also, putty worked perfectly after I read the screen which told me to use a username of 'core'.

'core' was a requirement of my configuration which was trying to launch CoreOS.

Answer (score 0):

Adding C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to the PATH environment variable didn't work for me.
So I configured PUTTY for ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

This well-written illustrative tutorial gives a great overview on ways to setup Vagrant SSH.  The first way is via Git and the second way describes how to use Putty.  It is very easy to follow.

[Running Vagrant SSH on Windows](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/10/22/run-vagrant-ssh-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case even adding ssh to the PATH didn't solve the problem. What I had to do is connect to vagrant with ssh manually. After executing vagrant up, instead of executing vagrant ssh, I do this:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

And the password is "vagrant"

For getting all the information about the ip, port and user you can use

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

Ope this helps somebody...