# How do you update the GIT_SSH environment variable on Windows

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit, and I've just upgraded Git for Windows from an older version to 2.7.2. In the process, the location of `ssh.exe` has moved from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe` to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.

This has broken my ability to fetch changes in TortoiseGit, since it can't find `ssh.exe` at the original location. Looking at Show Environment Variables in the settings (Image 1), I get a generated file with the `GIT_SSH` environment variable set to the old path (Image 2).

I have no idea where this is coming from. It doesn't appear to be part of Windows' environment variables.

Any idea where this is set so that I can change it?

#### Image 1 - Settings Window

[image: Settings Window]

#### Image 2 - GIT_SSH Environment Variable

[image: GIT_SSH Environment Variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enter 'ssh.exe' on TortoiseGit settings -> Network as SSH client. As TortoiseGit sets the PATH you don't need to enter the full path to ssh.exe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

- your keys in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit` (remove or amend any ssh one)
- as mentioned in "[How to install/setup TortoiseGit to work with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913276/6309)", `TortoiseGit->Settings->Network` (Set SSH Client property to `/bin/ssh.exe`)